# Polar/Stereographic map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, gis, cartography

I am trying to produce a sterographic map similarly to this:

[image]

What I am trying to do is to add:

1. Coordinates
2. Graticule lines

This can be in both base R or with ggplot2. Any help is appreciated.

**My attempts so far**

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)                                                                                                     

proj <- "+proj=stere +lat_0=90 +lat_ts=70 +lon_0=-45 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +a=6378273 +b=6356889.449 +units=m +no_defs"

data("wrld_simpl", package = "maptools")                                                                            
wm <- crop(wrld_simpl, extent(-180, 180, 45, 90))                                                                   
plot(wm)
```

[image]

```
wm <- spTransform(wm, CRSobj = CRS(proj))
plot(wm)
```

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is quite a complex map to reproduce, and all the details required to make it work seem beyond the scope of a single question. However, this is most of the stuff you require.

Doing this in ggplot is *easier* to do that using the base graphics. However, it is quite a complex graph to make.

I have had to use a few hacks to get it to work. In particular, the axes produced from `coord_map` did not end at the edge of the plot, so I had to manually delete the axes and then recreate them using the `geom_text` and `geom_segment` lines below.

```
library(rgdal)                                                                                                      
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

# Defines the x axes required
x_lines <- seq(-120,180, by = 60)

ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = wm_ggplot, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "grey", colour = "black", alpha = 0.8) +

  # Convert to polar coordinates
  coord_map("ortho", orientation = c(90, 0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(45, 90, by = 5), labels = NULL) +

  # Removes Axes and labels
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") +

  # Adds labels
  geom_text(aes(x = 180, y = seq(55, 85, by = 10), hjust = -0.2, label = paste0(seq(55, 85, by = 10), "°N"))) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x_lines, y = 39, label = c("120°W", "60°W", "0°", "60°E", "120°E", "180°W"))) +

  # Adds axes
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 45), size = 1)  +
  geom_segment(aes(y = 45, yend = 90, x = x_lines, xend = x_lines), linetype = "dashed") +

# Change theme to remove axes and ticks
theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
      panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'dashed',
                                      colour = "black"),
      axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
  labs(caption = "Designed by Mikey Harper")
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative solution using the [PlotSvalbard](https://github.com/MikkoVihtakari/PlotSvalbard) package:

```
# devtools::install_github("MikkoVihtakari/PlotSvalbard") ## Run once

library(PlotSvalbard)

basemap("panarctic", limits = 60)
```

[image]

The function also plots bathymetry:

```
basemap("panarctic", limits = 60, bathymetry = TRUE)
```

[image]

Check [the user manual](https://mikkovihtakari.github.io/PlotSvalbard/articles/PlotSvalbard_user_manual.html) for further features. Plotting data is possible using ggplot2 syntax. Use the [`add_land`](https://mikkovihtakari.github.io/PlotSvalbard/reference/add_land.html) function to add land shapes on top of the raster you need to plot (needs to be in the same projection than the Pan-Arctic basemaps, see `map_projection("panarctic")`). The [`transform_coord`](https://mikkovihtakari.github.io/PlotSvalbard/reference/transform_coord.html) function might be helpful for transforming projections.