# How to plot a sector of the south pole in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to plot some data over a map of Antarctica and I managed to do so following this thread

[Polar/Stereographic map in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48816773/polar-stereographic-map-in-r)

```
library(rgdal)                                                                                                      
library(raster)
library(ggplot2)

Long <- c(-75, -76, -77, -78, -79)
Lat  <- c(123, 124, 125, 126, 127)
Sodio<- c(110, 209, 65.7, 47.6, 135)
data<-data.frame(Long, Lat, Sodio)
# Defines the x axes required


 x_lines <- seq(-120,180, by = 60)
   wm <- map_data("world")
    ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = wm, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "grey", colour = "black", alpha = 0.8) +
  
  # Convert to polar coordinates
  coord_map("ortho", orientation = c(-90, 0, 0)) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(-90,-60),breaks = seq(-45, -90, by = -5), labels = NULL) +
  
  # Removes Axes and labels
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  xlab("") + 
  ylab("") +
  
  # Adds labels
  geom_text(aes(x = -160, y = seq(-55, -85, by = -10), hjust = -0.2, label = paste0(seq(55, 85, by = 10), "°S"))) +
  geom_text(aes(x = x_lines, y = -63, label = c("120°W", "60°W", "0°", "60°E", "120°E", "180°W"))) +
  
  # Adds axes
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = -60), size = 1)  +
  geom_segment(aes(y = -60, yend = -90, x = x_lines, xend = x_lines), linetype = "dashed") +
  
  
  # Change theme to remove axes and ticks
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        panel.grid.major = element_line(size = 0.25, linetype = 'dashed',
                                        colour = "black"),
        axis.ticks=element_blank()) +
  
  geom_point(data=data, aes(x=Long, y=Lat, color=Sodio))+
               scale_color_gradient(low="blue", high="red")
```

And the code works. Like a charm and kudos to the original user to posting it because it helped me a ton.
The problem is that since all the data are in a small sector (mostly between 85° and 65 °N and between 180° W and 130° W, the one I posted are just a super short dummy set) I was tryig to plot just that "wedge" of the Antarctic continent in order to help me visualize the data more clearly. I could just expland the plot and cut it with photoshop but I need to plot a number of these.

I tried changing the projection to a conic one but it starts doing... extremely weird stuff like trying to peoject the entirety of the world even when I try to put limits in the scale_y_continuous.

Any idea on how to solve this? Also, any idea on how I can add "elevation" lines on the map? I'm working in ggplot because I need to plot some data on top of it afterwards and I'm more familiar with that package of R, but I'm ok with other packages as long as they allow me to plot data on top of it and they can save the plot at 300 dpi...