# Placement of latitude labels in cartopy with polar stereographic projection

Tags: python, matplotlib, cartopy

I am trying to figure out how to change the placement of gridline labels (more specifically, latitude labels) in cartopy when using a polar stereographic projection (`NorthPolarStereo`). My axis currently looks like this:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs

# Helper function
# from https://nordicesmhub.github.io/NEGI-Abisko-2019/training/example_NorthPolarStereo_projection.html
def polarCentral_set_latlim(lat_lims, ax):
    ax.set_extent([-180, 180, lat_lims[0], lat_lims[1]], ccrs.PlateCarree())
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    center, radius = [0.5, 0.5], 0.5
    verts = np.vstack([np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]).T
    circle = mpath.Path(verts * radius + center)
    ax.set_boundary(circle, transform=ax.transAxes)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(6,6))
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1,projection=ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=0))
ax.coastlines(linewidth=0.5,color='k')
ax.gridlines(color='C7',lw=1,ls=':',draw_labels=True,rotate_labels=False,ylocs=[60,70,80])
polarCentral_set_latlim((50,90),ax)
```

[image: Polar stereographic plot with default position of gridline labels]

Oddly, the latitude labels are always plotted at about 150E even if the `central_longitude` is set to a different value. Preferably, I'd like to align them with the 180th meridian (similar to the labels in [this plot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49084793)) but I cannot find an option in the documentation of the [`gridlines`](https://scitools.org.uk/cartopy/docs/latest/reference/generated/cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.html?highlight=gridlines#cartopy.mpl.geoaxes.GeoAxes.gridlines) function to set their position. Did I overlook something or would I have to place them manually with `plt.text()`

Answer (score 2):

After the `gridlines` is created, some labels can be accessed and moved to new positions.
I use alternate method to define the circular boundary of the plot in order not to interfere with gridlines' labels.

```
import cartopy.crs as ccrs      #cartopy v0.19
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.path as mpath
import numpy as np

# Value for r_extent is obtained by trial and error
# get it with `ax.get_ylim()` after running this code
r_extent = 4651194.319
r_extent *= 1.005       #increase a bit for better result

# Projection settings  
lonlat_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()
use_proj = ccrs.NorthPolarStereo(central_longitude=0)
fig = plt.figure(figsize=[7, 7])
ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=use_proj)
ax.set_extent([-180, 180, 50, 90], lonlat_proj)

#ax.stock_img() # add bluemarble image
ax.coastlines(lw=0.5, color="black", zorder=20) # add coastlines

# draw graticule (meridian and parallel lines)
gls = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, crs=lonlat_proj, lw=1, color="gray",
        y_inline=True, xlocs=range(-180,180,30), ylocs=range(0,90,10))

# set the plot limits
ax.set_xlim(-r_extent, r_extent)
ax.set_ylim(-r_extent, r_extent)

# Prep circular boundary
circle_path = mpath.Path.unit_circle()
circle_path = mpath.Path(circle_path.vertices.copy() * r_extent,
                           circle_path.codes.copy())

#set circular boundary
#this method will not interfere with the gridlines' labels 
ax.set_boundary(circle_path)
ax.set_frame_on(False)  #hide the boundary frame

plt.draw()  # Enable the use of `gl._labels`

# Reposition the tick labels
# Labels at 150d meridian will be moved to 180d
for ea in gls._labels:
    # No _labels if not run `plt.draw()`
    pos = ea[2].get_position()
    #print("Position:", pos[0], pos[1])
    if (pos[0]==150):
        ea[2].set_position([180, pos[1]])

plt.show()
```

[image: output1]

**Edit** (Mar 3, 2023)

The code above worked well for Cartopy v0.19. The `gridlines` in newer versions has changed, and parts of the code need update.

Here is the relevant code:-

```
# ...
for ea in gls.label_artists:
    pos = ea.get_position()
    if pos[0] == 150:
        print("Position:", pos, ea.get_text() )
        ea.set_position([180, pos[1]])

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Might because of the cartopy version (0.21.1) I used but the the answer by @swatchai didn't work for me. Yet a slight change can be done and will work fine.

```
plt.draw()
for ea in gls.label_artists:
    # return ea of mpl.text type, e.g. Text(135, 30, '30°N') 
    pos = ea.get_position()
    if pos[0] == 135:
        ea.set_position([180, pos[1]])
```

Comment: Can you explain why this change needed to be done?

Comment: The original code by @swatchai cannot be applied on cartopy > 0.19.0.  The new Label object was introduced since the version 0.20.0.. Label objects (constructed by a class Label) are strored in the list Gridliner._labels, with properties artist, loc, path, xy and priority. `gls.label_artists` accesses the artist property of each Label object, which is of mpl.text type.

Comment: Older cartopy versions such as 0.19.0 construst `gls._labels` as a list storing tuples of `(lonlat, priority, tt)` with text type tt (`pos` here) of `(x, y , text)`. That's why the original code works before cartopy version 0.20.0.

Comment: Hi.
Thanks for the proposed solution. However, I cannot get your example to work. It doesn't do anything to the labels. Any idea why?  I am on cartopy 0.21.0

Comment: Sorry but I don't see a lot change in the source code from 0.21.0 to 0.21.1, maybe you could provide some more information?