# How do I plot netCDF sea ice extent dataset in Python?

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray, cartopy

I am planning to plot sea ice extent around Antarctica using NOAA-NSIDC Passive Microwave Sea Ice Concentration, Version 4 dataset in Python. I am using the following code:

```
>>> import xarray as xr
>>> import numpy as np
>>> import cmocean
>>> import cartopy.crs as ccrs
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
>>> import cartopy.feature as cfeature
>>> from cartopy.mpl.gridliner import LONGITUDE_FORMATTER, LATITUDE_FORMATTER
>>> # Read in the netCDF file
>>>
>>> ds = xr.open_dataset('seaice_conc_monthly_sh_202212_f17_v04r00.nc')
>>> # Extract the sea ice extent data for the first time step
>>>
>>> sea_ice_extent = ds.cdr_seaice_conc_monthly.sel(tdim=ds.tdim[0]).values
>>> # Extract the x and y grid coordinates
>>>
>>> xgrid = ds.xgrid.values
>>> ygrid = ds.ygrid.values
>>> # Create the plot
>>>
>>> fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 10))
>>> ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.SouthPolarStereo())
>>> ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -60], ccrs.PlateCarree())
>>> im = ax.pcolormesh(xgrid, ygrid, sea_ice_extent, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(), cmap='cmo.ice')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", line 318, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", line 1787, in pcolormesh
    result = self._wrap_quadmesh(result, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", line 1970, in _wrap_quadmesh
    pcolor_col = self.pcolor(coords[..., 0], coords[..., 1],
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", line 318, in wrapper
    return func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", line 2015, in pcolor
    limits = result.get_datalim(self.transData)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 266, in get_datalim
    paths = [transform.transform_path_non_affine(p) for p in paths]
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 266, in <listcomp>
    paths = [transform.transform_path_non_affine(p) for p in paths]
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 2431, in transform_path_non_affine
    return self._a.transform_path_non_affine(path)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", line 190, in transform_path_non_affine
    proj_geom = self.target_projection.project_geometry(
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 808, in project_geometry
    return getattr(self, method_name)(geometry, src_crs)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 963, in _project_polygon
    return self._rings_to_multi_polygon(rings, is_ccw)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 1224, in _rings_to_multi_polygon
    multi_poly = sgeom.MultiPolygon(polygon_bits)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\multipolygon.py", line 79, in __new__
    shell = ob[0]
TypeError: 'GeometryCollection' object is not subscriptable
>>> ax.gridlines()
<cartopy.mpl.gridliner.Gridliner object at 0x000001EE3C35B8E0>
>>> ax.coastlines()
<cartopy.mpl.feature_artist.FeatureArtist object at 0x000001EE3C31FE80>
>>> gl = ax.gridlines(draw_labels=True, linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')
>>> gl.top_labels = False
>>> gl.right_labels = False
>>> gl.xformatter = LONGITUDE_FORMATTER
>>> gl.yformatter = LATITUDE_FORMATTER
>>> cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, shrink=0.4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'im' is not defined. Did you mean: 'id'?
>>> cbar.ax.set_ylabel('Sea Ice Concentration (%)', fontsize=16)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'cbar' is not defined
>>> plt.show()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_qt.py", line 468, in _draw_idle
    self.draw()
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\backends\backend_agg.py", line 400, in draw
    self.figure.draw(self.renderer)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 95, in draw_wrapper
    result = draw(artist, renderer, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 3140, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", line 538, in draw
    return super().draw(renderer=renderer, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 3064, in draw
    mimage._draw_list_compositing_images(
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 131, in _draw_list_compositing_images
    a.draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 972, in draw
    super().draw(renderer)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py", line 72, in draw_wrapper
    return draw(artist, renderer)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 351, in draw
    transform, offset_trf, offsets, paths = self._prepare_points()
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 328, in _prepare_points
    paths = [transform.transform_path_non_affine(path)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 328, in <listcomp>
    paths = [transform.transform_path_non_affine(path)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\transforms.py", line 2431, in transform_path_non_affine
    return self._a.transform_path_non_affine(path)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\mpl\geoaxes.py", line 190, in transform_path_non_affine
    proj_geom = self.target_projection.project_geometry(
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 808, in project_geometry
    return getattr(self, method_name)(geometry, src_crs)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 963, in _project_polygon
    return self._rings_to_multi_polygon(rings, is_ccw)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\cartopy\crs.py", line 1224, in _rings_to_multi_polygon
    multi_poly = sgeom.MultiPolygon(polygon_bits)
  File "C:\Users\ashif\miniconda3\lib\site-packages\shapely\geometry\multipolygon.py", line 79, in __new__
    shell = ob[0]
TypeError: 'GeometryCollection' object is not subscriptable
```

However I am facing the following error:

```
TypeError: 'GeometryCollection' object is not subscriptable
```

Could anyone tell me how do I plot this in a projection that is suitable for the south poles? Below are some of the information about the dataset:

```
Attributes:
    long_name:            NOAA/NSIDC Climate Data Record of Passive Microwave...
    standard_name:        sea_ice_area_fraction
    units:                1
    flag_values:          [251 252 253 254 255]
    flag_meanings:        pole_hole lakes coastal land_mask missing_data
    datum:                +ellps=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
    grid_mapping:         projection
    reference:            https://nsidc.org/data/g02202/versions/4/
    ancillary_variables:  stdev_of_cdr_seaice_conc_monthly qa_of_cdr_seaice_c...
    valid_range:          [  0 100], 'nsidc_bt_seaice_conc_monthly': <xarray.Variable (tdim: 1, y: 332, x: 316)>
[104912 values with dtype=float32]
Attributes:
    long_name:      Passive Microwave Monthly Southern Hemisphere Sea Ice Con...
    standard_name:  sea_ice_area_fraction
    units:          1
    flag_values:    [251 252 253 254 255]
    flag_meanings:  pole_hole unused coastal land_mask missing_data
    datum:          +ellps=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
    grid_mapping:   projection
    valid_range:    [  0 100], 'nsidc_nt_seaice_conc_monthly': <xarray.Variable (tdim: 1, y: 332, x: 316)>
[104912 values with dtype=float32]
Attributes:
    long_name:      Passive Microwave Monthly Southern Hemisphere Sea Ice Con...
    standard_name:  sea_ice_area_fraction
    units:          1
    flag_values:    [251 252 253 254 255]
    flag_meanings:  pole_hole unused coastal land_mask missing_data
    datum:          +ellps=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
    grid_mapping:   projection
    valid_range:    [  0 100], 'projection': <xarray.Variable ()>
[1 values with dtype=|S1]
Attributes: (12/23)
    grid_boundary_top_projected_y:          4350000.0
    grid_boundary_bottom_projected_y:       -3950000.0
    grid_boundary_right_projected_x:        3950000.0
    grid_boundary_left_projected_x:         -3950000.0
    parent_grid_cell_row_subset_start:      0.0
    parent_grid_cell_row_subset_end:        332.0
    ...                                     ...
    scaling_factor:                         1.0
    false_easting:                          0.0
    false_northing:                         0.0
    semimajor_radius:                       6378273.0
    semiminor_radius:                       6356889.449
    units:                                  meters, 'qa_of_cdr_seaice_conc_monthly': <xarray.Variable (tdim: 1, y: 332, x: 316)>
[104912 values with dtype=float32]
Attributes:
    long_name:      Passive Microwave Monthly Southern Hemisphere Sea Ice Con...
    standard_name:  sea_ice_area_fraction status_flag
    flag_meanings:  Average_concentration_exceeds_0.15 Average_concentration_...
    datum:          +ellps=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
    grid_mapping:   projection
    flag_masks:     [  1   2   4   8  32  64 128]
    valid_range:    [  1 255], 'stdev_of_cdr_seaice_conc_monthly': <xarray.Variable (tdim: 1, y: 332, x: 316)>
[104912 values with dtype=float32]
Attributes:
    long_name:     Passive Microwave Monthly Southern Hemisphere Sea Ice Conc...
    datum:         +ellps=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::4326
    grid_mapping:  projection
    valid_range:   [0. 1.], 'time': <xarray.Variable (tdim: 1)>
[1 values with dtype=datetime64[ns]]
Attributes:
    standard_name:  time
    long_name:      ANSI date
    axis:           T, 'xgrid': <xarray.Variable (x: 316)>
array([-3937500., -3912500., -3887500., ...,  3887500.,  3912500.,  3937500.],
      dtype=float32)
Attributes:
    valid_range:    [-3950000.  3950000.]
    units:          meters
    long_name:      projection_grid_x_centers
    standard_name:  projection_x_coordinate
    axis:           X, 'ygrid': <xarray.Variable (y: 332)>
array([ 4337500.,  4312500.,  4287500., ..., -3887500., -3912500., -3937500.],
      dtype=float32)
Attributes:
    valid_range:    [-3950000.  4350000.]
    units:          meters
    long_name:      projection_grid_y_centers
    standard_name:  projection_y_coordinate
    axis:           Y}))
```

The following variables are in the dataset:

```
cdr_seaice_conc_monthly           (tdim, y, x) float32 ...
    nsidc_bt_seaice_conc_monthly      (tdim, y, x) float32 ...
    nsidc_nt_seaice_conc_monthly      (tdim, y, x) float32 ...
    projection                        |S1 ...
    qa_of_cdr_seaice_conc_monthly     (tdim, y, x) float32 ...
    stdev_of_cdr_seaice_conc_monthly  (tdim, y, x) float32 ...
```

I would like to get a plot similar to this:

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the full traceback and make it clear which line is throwing the error?

Comment: @RobertWilson Thanks for taking the time to respond, since the traceback is too big, I am posting an image of it: https://i.imgur.com/1DYWBe8.png

Comment: Please modify the question so it's clear which line is causing the issue. Any reader will assume it's the final line. In fact the final 10 lines seem irrelevant to the problem

Comment: I have modified the question with full traceback, I hope this will provide some context to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that you're specifying the projection of the data to be `ccrs.PlateCarree()`, which clearly is incorrect.

There might be a better way than to parse it as in the example below, but it captures the gist:

```py
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects

with xr.open_dataset("seaice_conc_monthly_sh_202212_f17_v04r00.nc") as ds:

    sea_ice_extent = ds.cdr_seaice_conc_monthly.sel(tdim=ds.tdim[0]).values * 100

    data_proj = ccrs.epsg(ds.projection.attrs["srid"].split("::")[-1])
    
    flags = ds.cdr_seaice_conc_monthly.attrs["flag_values"]
    
    invalid = np.isin(sea_ice_extent, flags)
    sea_ice_extent[invalid] = np.nan
    
    xgrid = ds.xgrid.values
    ygrid = ds.ygrid.values

cmap = mpl.colormaps["BuPu"].copy()
cmap.set_bad("grey", alpha=.2)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(
    figsize=(8,8), facecolor="w",
    subplot_kw=dict(projection=ccrs.SouthPolarStereo()),
)

im = ax.pcolormesh(xgrid, ygrid, sea_ice_extent, transform=data_proj, cmap=cmap)

ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -45], ccrs.PlateCarree())
ax.coastlines()

gl = ax.gridlines(
    draw_labels=True, 
    lw=0.4, 
    ylabel_style=dict(path_effects=[PathEffects.withStroke(linewidth=2, foreground="w")]),
    xlocs=range(-180,180,45), ylocs=range(-90,0,10),
    y_inline=True,
)
cbar = fig.colorbar(im, ax=ax, shrink=0.4, label='Sea Ice Concentration (%)')

ax.set_boundary(mpl.path.Path.circle((0, 0), 3950000*1.2), transform=data_proj)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I was able to get a similar plot. However, I have a question about netCDF datasets. These datasets have coordinates in xgrid and ygrid rather than latitude and longitude. Do I need to transform the grids? Also, could you tell me how to get coordinate labels in the plot? I tried using the following code, but it didn’t work:
```ax.text(-178, -89, "({:.0f}$^\circ$W, {:.0f}$^\circ$S)".format(-180, -90), transform=ccrs.SouthPolarStereo(), ha='left', va='bottom', fontsize=10)```
Once again, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: When you plot something, you should provide the projection of the data. Only when creating the subplot do you need to define the projection of the map.

So if you want to plot text with lat/lon, use `transform=ccrs.PlateCarree()`, that should make the text show in the figure. 

I've update the example a little to add some coordinate labels.

Cartopy doesn't label these polar plots very nicely, but see for example this post for a nice method: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/74003721/1755432

Comment: It is already beautiful! I could use your modified code and plot the graph with some modifications of my own. Thank you once again. I noticed that when I subset axis extent from ```ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -45], ccrs.PlateCarree())``` to ```ax.set_extent([-180, 180, -90, -60], ccrs.PlateCarree())``` the circular plot turns into a square shape: https://imgur.com/a/zSiThYk. I guess it has something to do with projection again. is there any way to retain the circular shape after submitting?

Comment: You can adjust the value in the `set_boundary` call to the appropriate value for what -60 would be in the SouthPolar() projection. Or alternatively check the link above and use the "circular boundary" part from that code, which relates it to the axes instead of the projection/extent, so that wouldn't change when changing the extent.

Comment: I am indebted to you. I was able to use the "circular boundary" part from the earlier link and fix a radius that would clip the figure to show up to 60 degrees south. Here is the modified code if you would like to see it: https://github.com/Asheef1447/Antarctic-Sea-Ice-Plot-in-Python/blob/c8aeb9fa393f6da4a9e018e90f163016f34b3741/Sea_ice.ipynb

Comment: Looks great, well done .